# HTML Emails - code for email sent date

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm designing an HTML email. At one point, I'm needing to insert the email sent date in my email body. Let me explain the situation..

So there is a coupon code which will expire after three days of the email being sent. In one of the `<p>` element, I need to insert the sent date (+3 days). To my knowledge this is not achievable by plain HTML and CSS. Can anyone confirm this?

Any guide to how to achieve this is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Yes, without knowing which mailing service you're using, there's no way to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

besides the point that this is off topic I'll try my best to help:

I don't know with what provider you send you Mails and Campaigns, but if you use Campaign Monitor, you can add personalisation tags in your Mail to show the date. Here is a Link to a Reference, showing how this works: [Personailsation CM](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/personalization/)

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I do not have access to the email provider, I believe it is a custom made one, not any of the web email providers. I'm only designing the HTML template. Many thanks.

Comment: Ask wich Mail is being used. It's importent for designing the Mail, since every provieder sends it a little bit different. For example I had trouble with a Mail I send with Mailchimp, but the Mail send from Campaign Monitor was fine. You'll need to test your HTML with the Provider to be sure it'll be send correctly